# Slow loading of pages (browser performance)

Tags: 12.10, firefox, google-chrome, performance, browser

I have `Ubuntu 12.10` installed. I notice for certain webpages, `firefox` and `chrome` both load them very slowly. In fact, while text content loads quickly, both of the browsers seem to be loading something else for long long time. And some webpages do not load at all (only when I press `refresh` I see, for a split moment that content was indeed loaded but was not displayed). Of course this constant loading of content saps CPU, fan starts running speedily, and returns to normal when I stop these constant loading pages.

This problem does not occur in `Windows 7` on the same laptop.

What's the problem?

Comment: Does this still occur after a re-start, or at any time?

Comment: As always, specifying at least some of the sites may help you get help faster.

Comment: I have a problem that seems similar - text input and scrolling in Firefox is extremely slow after installing 12.10 using my old home folder. Have not found a solution yet. Restart does not help.